# Combine Nokogiri XML Builders

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I like the `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` construct, but it would be easier to assemble large XML documents if I could modularize the building process further by splitting the job among several builders.

Does anybody see a way to **get multiple builders to cooperate**? (for instance, a parent builder calling functions that set child builders to create smaller portions of the document)

Or is there a way to modify a builder after its block terminates? (---short of outputting XML, then parsing it into a Nokogiri::XML::Document, then adding nodes, then outputting XML again)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Delegating Builder Functionality

> *for instance, a parent builder calling functions that set child builders to create smaller portions of the document*

You can easily delegate responsibility to methods that take the builder's current state and use it. For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

def add_kids_for(name,xml)
  xml.send(name){ 1.upto(3){ |i| xml.kid("#{name}'s kid ##{i}") } }
end

build = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root do
    add_kids_for("Danny",xml)
    add_kids_for("Billy",xml)
  end
end
puts build.to_xml
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <root>
#=>   <Danny>
#=>     <kid>Danny's kid #1</kid>
#=>     <kid>Danny's kid #2</kid>
#=>     <kid>Danny's kid #3</kid>
#=>   </Danny>
#=>   <Billy>
#=>     <kid>Billy's kid #1</kid>
#=>     <kid>Billy's kid #2</kid>
#=>     <kid>Billy's kid #3</kid>
#=>   </Billy>
#=> </root>
```

Just pass the `xml` (or whatever you call your builder object) to the method and let that method do what it needs to (either procedurally or manually).

### Modifying a Builder after Creation

> *Or is there a way to modify a builder after its block terminates?*

Yes! :) You want to the `doc` method of the Builder to get the `Nokogiri::XML::Document` driving it. Carrying on the above example:

```
doc = build.doc
doc.css('kid').each do |kid|
  kid['name'] = %w[Bobby Jenny Jill Sam Gish Gavin Lisa Imogen Lachlan].sample
end
puts doc
#=> <root>
#=>   <Danny>
#=>     <kid name="Lisa">Danny's kid #1</kid>
#=>     <kid name="Imogen">Danny's kid #2</kid>
#=>     <kid name="Lachlan">Danny's kid #3</kid>
#=>   </Danny>
#=>   <Billy>
#=>     <kid name="Gish">Billy's kid #1</kid>
#=>     <kid name="Gavin">Billy's kid #2</kid>
#=>     <kid name="Sam">Billy's kid #3</kid>
#=>   </Billy>
#=> </root>
```